# Error compiling Jersey library different Java version

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jersey, version

I just finished a program "Maven java project". I am using Jersey library/.

I need to compile and run my program in java 1.4.

I am changing the compliance to 1.4 in Eclipse.

plus adapting the pom.xml

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.4</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Now I am getting errors concerning certain classes:

[image: code showing the error]

[image: Error 2 jersey and java 1.4]

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: __Q:__ why is target 1.4 anyway? Sounds not logical.

Comment: I need to deploy it on an old system that uses java 1.4.2.

Comment: I think the earliest version of Java you can use is `1.5.0_13`. I'm looking at the MANIFEST for [Jersey 1.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle/1.0), and it as that version as the JDK build

Comment: Ok that helps thank you for your comment!!

Answer (score 1):

Jersey is not compatible with Java 1.4. Neither is the <> syntax. You really should at least use java 1.6.

Comment: what do you advise me to do then to inject json objects on a server from a java 1.4 environment?

Comment: I would **very** strongly advice upgrading your java version. 1.4 has been obsolete for a very long time. If that's not possible, you could first have a look at Jackson for JSON serialization.

Comment: Update server to newer Java version.

Comment: If newer version is not possible, try to set it up as an separate web-app, which just handles the JSON API stuff. Split from the original web-app, if possible.

Comment: I guess I am stuck because I am not allowed to update the server! I need to see if it is possible to create a seperate web app on the os that I am working on!! thank you